# UISlider switch maximumValue and minimumValue

Tags: swift, uikit

I want that my slider works if the minimumValue is larger than the maximumValue. But if i switch the values I can't slide anymore.

Currently:

```
    mySlider.minimumValue = 0.001
    mySlider.maximumValue = 0.5
    mySlider.value = 0.05
    mySlider.isContinuous = true
```

I want:

```
    mySlider.minimumValue = 0.5
    mySlider.maximumValue = 0.001
```

Comment: You cannot have the minimum value larger that the maximum value.

Comment: ...but you can derive the inverse value manually (`1 - value` for a `0...1` range for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of the slider can map to a real value. So for example if you want values going from 0.5 to 0.0001, you could set a UISlider to slide between 0 and 100, and then based on the slider's value, the computed value would be 0.5 - slider's percent * (0.5 - 0.0001)